# Optimize finding pairs of arrays which can be compared

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, numpy

Definition: Array `A(a1,a2,...,an)` is `>=` than `B(b1,b2,...bn)` if they are equal sized and `a_i>=b_i` for every `i` from `1` to `n.`

For example:

```
[1,2,3] >= [1,2,0]
[1,2,0] not comparable with [1,0,2]
[1,0,2] >= [1,0,0]
```

I have a list which consists of a big number of such arrays (approx. 10000, but can be bigger). Arrays' elements are positive integers. I need to remove all arrays from this list that are bigger than at least one of other arrays. In other words: if there exists such `B` that `A >= B` then remove `A`.

Here is my current `O(n^2)` approach which is extremely slow. I simply compare every array with all other arrays and remove it if it's bigger. Are there any ways to speed it up.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

def filter_minimal(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    to_delete = set()
    for i in xrange(n-1):
        if i in to_delete:
            continue
        for j in xrange(i+1,n):
            if j in to_delete: continue
            if all(lst[i]>=lst[j]):
                to_delete.add(i)
                break
            elif all(lst[i]<=lst[j]):
                to_delete.add(j)
    return [lst[i] for i in xrange(len(lst)) if i not in to_delete]


def test(number_of_arrays,size):
    x = map(np.array,[[random.randrange(0,10) for _ in xrange(size)] for i in xrange(number_of_arrays)])
    return filter_minimal(x)

a = time.time()
result = test(400,10)
print time.time()-a
print len(result)
```

P.S. I've noticed that using `numpy.all` instead of builtin python `all` slows the program dramatically. What can be the reason?

Comment: So you want the smallest array?  What do you do about arrays that are not able to be compared... I'm not following ...

Comment: No. I need to remove all arrays that compare to smaller ones. For example: List([1,2,3], [1,2,1], [1,0,2]). I need to remove [1,2,3] because it's bigger than [1,2,1]. However, I can't do anything with [1,0,2] because it can't be compared with any other array.

Comment: So at the end, you're only left with arrays which can't be compared to each other?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I need. This is a part of TSS algorithm for solving sets of diophantine equations.

Comment: Why are `[1,2,0]` and `[1,0,2]` not comparable? Just that the first n-1 indices are not equal? Another `O(N^2)` method to consider, but likely to be much faster is using higher dimensional numpy arrays instead of all of these loops.

Comment: I'm thinking of some bucket approaches. But can't find the correct way to apply them here.

Comment: @Ophion if we zip([1,2,0],[1,0,2]) and map >= operator, we will get [True, True, False]. This means that arrays are not comparable. If the result was [True, True, True], we would have said that they are comparable and first array is bigger than second. Not comparable I mean that we can't say neither `[1,2,0]>=[1,0,2]` nor `[1,2,0] <= [1,0,2]`

Comment: That isn't what "not comparable" means. That means you compared them and the result was false.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you are asking for, but this should get you started.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

def compare(x,y):
    #Reshape x to a higher dimensional array
    compare_array=x.reshape(-1,1,x.shape[-1])
    #You can now compare every x with every y element wise simultaneously
    mask=(y>=compare_array)
    #Create a mask that first ensures that all elements of y are greater then x and
    #then ensure that this is the case at least once.
    mask=np.any(np.all(mask,axis=-1),axis=-1)
    #Places this mask on x
    return x[mask]

def test(number_of_arrays,size,maxval):
    #Create arrays of size (number_of_arrays,size) with maximum value maxval.
    x = np.random.randint(maxval, size=(number_of_arrays,size))
    y=  np.random.randint(maxval, size=(number_of_arrays,size))
    return compare(x,y)

print test(50,10,20)
```

Comment: Well, nice vectorized approach, but this is still O(N^2). If I don't find anything better I would probably just rewrite that function in pure C.

Comment: At best you will have O(N log(N)) scaling to this, I believe the only implementation of the required ideas is the scipy KDTree, but of course does not do what you want it to do. AFAIK there is nothing in numpy or scipy that does what you want and if you are that concerned about speed you are much better off writing this in C.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to carefully check the objective. Is it true that we delete any array that is > ANY of the other arrays, even the deleted ones? For example, if A > B and C > A and B=C, then do we need to delete only A or both A and C? If we only need to delete INCOMPATIBLE arrays, then it is a much harder problem. This is a very difficult problem because different partitions of the set of arrays may be compatible, so you have the problem of finding the largest valid partition.

Assuming the easy problem, a better way to define the problem is that you want to KEEP all arrays which have at least one element < the corresponding element in ALL the other arrays. (In the hard problem, it is the corresponding element in the other KEPT arrays. We will not consider this.)

Stage 1

To solve this problem what you do is arrange the arrays in columns and then sort each row while maintaining the key to the array and the mapping of each array-row to position (POSITION lists). For example, you might end up with a result in stage 1 like this:

row 1:  B C D A E
row 2:  C A E B D
row 3:  E D B C A

Meaning that for the first element (row 1) array B has a value >= C, C >= D, etc.

Now, sort and iterate the last column of this matrix ({E D A} in the example). For each item, check if the element is less than the previous element in its row. For example, in row 1, you would check if E < A. If this is true you return immediately and keep the result. For example, if E_row1 < A_row1 then you can keep array E. Only if the values in the row are equal do you need to do a stage 2 test (see below).

In the example shown you would keep E, D, A (as long as they passed the test above).

Stage 2

This leaves B and C. Sort the POSITION list for each. For example, this will tell you that the row with B's mininum position is row 2. Now do a direct comparison between B and every array below it in the mininum row, here row 2. Here there is only one such array, D. Do a direct comparison between B and D. This shows that B < D in row 3, therefore B is compatible with D. If the item is compatible with every array below its minimum position keep it. We keep B.

Now we do the same thing for C. In C's case we need only do one direct comparison, with A. C dominates A so we do not keep C.

Note that in addition to testing items that did not appear in the last column we need to test items that had equality in Stage 1. For example, imagine D=A=E in row 1. In this case we would have to do direct comparisons for every equality involving the array in the last column. So, in this case we direct compare E to A and E to D. This shows that E dominates D, so E is not kept.

The final result is we keep A, B, and D. C and E are discarded.

The overall performance of this algorithm is n2*log n in Stage 1 + { n lower bound, n * log n - upper bound } in Stage 2. So, maximum running time is n2*log n + nlogn and minimum running time is n2logn + n. Note that the running time of your algorithm is n-cubed n3. Since you compare each matrix (n*n) and each comparison is n element comparisons = n*n*n.

In general, this will be much faster than the brute force approach. Most of the time will be spent sorting the original matrix, a more or less unavoidable task. Note that you could potentially improve my algorithm by using priority queues instead of sorting, but the resulting algorithm would be much more complicated.